# Navigation Components - onSupportNavigateUp()

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

Is it really necessary to call

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp() = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigateUp()
```

in my MainActivity ?

Because when I attach the NavHostFragment in my xml it starts from there, but I have seen the Google I/O lecture where they use it to make the start point of the navigation

My question

Where is it necessary to use it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`onSupportNavigateUp` comes from `AppCompatActivity`. You should override the method in the same activity where you define your `NavHostFragment` (probably your MainActivity). You override it so that the `NavigationUI` can correctly support the up navigation or even the drawer layout menu. `AppCompatActivity` and `NavigationUI` are two indepenent components, so you override the method in order to connect the two. Note that if you set a toolbar with the navigation component, i.e., if you do something similar to

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

  // ...

  val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
  val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
  findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar).setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
}
```

you don't need to override the `onSupportNavigationUp` method as Navigation will automatically handle the click events.

You also don't need to override it if you want to handle the toolbar yourself.

Comment: I dont have a toolbar for the momment, my question is just if its a matter implementing it or not because the code works the same without it

Comment: @CoffeeBreak then no, there's no need to implement it. You'll need it when you have a toolbar and want the navigation component to handle the up button navigation for you.

Comment: thats where I'm confused, which one is the up button ? I only know about the home button or back button from the toolbar

Comment: The up button is that little arrow that shows up in the left corner of the toolbar.

Comment: Thats whay I known as homebutton or toolbar back button, what a weird convention haha

Comment: Haha yeah I know, it's kinda weird. It's called "up" because when you press it, you're going "up" in the view hierarchy :)

Comment: How can we set this up in a Fragment instead of main Activity?